# Is it a good practice to call a jquery plugin from an angular directive

Tags: angularjs, jquery-plugins, angularjs-directive

Our project uses various jquery plugins. We are trying to convert it into angularjs. What is the right approach in terms of implementing such a functionality in angular perspective. is it correct to a write directive for each plugin and call the jquery plugin internally it or do we have any standard approach.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

> Try to use Angularjs plugins rather than jquery plugin

If you are using jquery plugin then you have to take care of **$digest cycle** because your jQuery plugin may have **setTimeout()** inside which make angular out of $digest loop, so it may be possible that you may got trouble in getting $scope values.